# Attempting to push into array gives error in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, push

I want to sort the array and to store the fetched values into a new array for print. I tried with push() but there is an error is occurring and shows that" Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

`

```
this.dataService.userprofile().subscribe((data:any) => {
      let profile:any[]=data.profiles;
      for(let index=0;index<profile.length;index++) {
        const element = profile[index];  
        const today: number = Date.now();
        var b = Math.abs(today - Date.parse(element["dob"]));
        element["dob"] = Math.floor(b / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365.25));
        if (element["active"]=="N"){
          this.row.push(element); 
        }}
      this.rowData = this.row;//ag-grid row
      console.log(this.rowData)
    })
```

`

Comment: Is `this.row` initialized in any way in the context of your function ?

Comment: `this.row = (this.row || []).concat(element);`

Comment: @Paqman i think `row` is a local variable to store the array of `element`s and populate the initialized `this.rowData`.. In my answer i suggest to work directly with `this.rowData` assigning the result of `Array.prototype.reduce()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `for loop` that it is hard to read and maintain you better use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and using the dot notation

Also notice that in TypeScript you should avoid using type `any`

Code:

```
this.dataService.userprofile().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.rowData = data.profiles.reduce((acc, element) => {
    const b = Math.abs(today - Date.parse(element.dob));
    element.dob = Math.floor(b / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365.25));
    return element.active == 'N' ? [...acc, element] : acc;
  }, []);

  console.log(this.rowData)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `row` variable before `for` loop.

```
this.dataService.userprofile().subscribe((data:any) => {
      let profile:any[]=data.profiles;
      let row = [];
      for(let index=0;index<profile.length;index++) {
        const element = profile[index];  
        const today: number = Date.now();
        var b = Math.abs(today - Date.parse(element["dob"]));
        element["dob"] = Math.floor(b / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365.25));
        if (element["active"]=="N"){
          row.push(element); 
        }}
      this.rowData = row;//ag-grid row
      console.log(this.rowData)
    })
```